# При каждом вызове дочернего окна, программа потребляет все больше памяти

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, qmainwindow

Допустим, у меня есть код (с главным и дочерним окном):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import  QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton


class ChildWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)  
        self.setWindowTitle("child window")
        self.resize(400, 100)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("main window")
        self.resize(400, 100)
         
        self.button = QPushButton("child window", self)
        self.button.setGeometry(0,0, 200, 50)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.createChildWindow)

    def createChildWindow(self):
        self.window = ChildWindow(self)
        self.window.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Если пользователь вызовет дочернее окно и закроет, то количество потребляемой памяти программой увеличиться, несмотря на закрытие. 
Получается с каждым вызовом количество потребляемой памяти будет увеличиваться.

[image: Потребление памяти]

(При запуске программа потребляла 10 МБ, после нескольких вызовов дочернего окна 15,2 МБ)

Почему дочернее окно ест память, даже если его закрыть? 
Как это исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import  QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton


class ChildWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ChildWindow, self).__init__(parent)  
        self.setWindowTitle("child window")
        self.resize(400, 100)
    

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("main window")
         
        self.button = QPushButton("child window", self)
        self.button.setGeometry(0, 0, 200, 50)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.createChildWindow)
        
        self.window = ChildWindow(self)                           # +++

    def createChildWindow(self):
#        self.window = ChildWindow(self)                          # ---
        self.window.show()
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.resize(500, 500)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

При закрытии окна объект, который вы создали:

```py
self.window = ChildWindow(self)
```

не удаляется из памяти.